# Java Applet > Convert "Unicode to Hex" (get Unicode of TextArea and display HEX values)

Tags: java, utf-8, hex

I'm having some trouble to Convert UNICODE to HEX values.. 
I couldn't find proper reference on web and discussion in StackOverflow are based on "HEX to unicode only".

What I need is some what similar but some modification like this (ONLY Java escapes)

http://javaboutique.internet.com/unicode/

The applet above displays the HEX values of UTF-8 those are pasted on the TextArea.

What I need is, to get the HEX values of the Unicode of the TextArea and assign them in a variable or display them.

The basic Startup I've is as follows.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class unicodeToHEX
extends      Applet
{
    TextField output;
    TextArea  input;

    public void init() {
        output = new TextField("Click for 'Text to speech' ",40);
        add(output);
        input  = new TextArea( "Type text here",8,40);
        add(input);
        output.setEditable(false);
    }

    public boolean gotFocus( Event evt, Object what ) {
        if (evt.target == input) {
        output.setText("Type text in below text area");
    }
    return super.gotFocus( evt, what );
    }

    public boolean lostFocus( Event evt, Object what ) {

        // Have super handle character entry:
        boolean result = super.lostFocus( evt, what );

        if (evt.target == input) {
            // Get string in input textfield:
            String s = input.getText();

            // Count newlines:
            int  len   = s.length();
            int  newlines = 0;
                for (int i = len;   i --> 0; ) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == '\n')   ++newlines;
            }





            // Report linecount in output textfield:
            output.setText("Text area contains " + newlines + " newlines");

        }

    return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = input.getText().getBytes("UTF-8");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4));
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    sb.append("-"); // place "-" between each conversion
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // remove trailing "-"
String hex = sb.toString();

output.setText("Text area UTF-8 in hex: " + hex);
```

Comment: Whitefang34, I'm dummy in java I've problem with **for (byte b : bytes) {** I didn't actually get it..

Comment: That's a [For-Each Loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). It's the same as `for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) { byte b = bytes[i];`

Comment: Thanks WhiteFang34, I managed to get the result but a small problem.. how do I add additional character within this for loop .. Suppose i want to add "-" character between each conversion.

Comment: No problem. I added "-" character between each conversion to the code to show how.

Comment: Matt, I wanted to contact you for another project which I don't want to make public. But I couldn't find your email to send, how should I contact you personally?

Comment: @OpenCode: sorry, I'm not available for personal contact. Perhaps you could try to find a way to ask your question in public?

Comment: Thankyou WhiteFang34, Here's the problem which I'll delete after a couple of hours http://tinyurl.com/678gn5y

Comment: @OpenCode: I don't have experience with the technologies mentioned for that project, so I can't offer any advice. What you're asking for doesn't sound trivial either, it sounds like a project that would take some time. This site is more about answering specific questions to smaller problems. People here like me aren't paid to answer and do so in our free time, we just do it because we enjoy to and hope that it can help others. You probably need to look elsewhere for consulting with a larger project. Or consider how to break the problem down into smaller questions that you can ask publicly.